# How to check if that which is iterated upon is the last key/value in a dict? (probably needs to be done in django template)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

The desired outcome is a navigation that look like so:
A | B | C | D | E | ... | X | Y | Z

Note that both A and Z do not have the pipe on the outsides.

This is the template I have currently.

```
<section id="partners_nav">
<div class="row">
    <table align="center" cellpadding="4px">
        <tr>
        {% for key, value in index.items %}
            {% if key in index|last %}
                {% if value == None %}
                <td>{{ key }}</td>
                <td id="partners_nav_bracket">|</td>
                {% else %}
                    <td><a href="{{ value }}">{{ key }}</a></td>
                    <td id="partners_nav_bracket">|</td>
                {% endif %}
            {% else %}
                {% if value == None %}
                    <td>{{ key }}</td>
                    <td id="partners_nav_bracket">|</td>
                {% else %}
                    <td><a href="{{ value }}">{{ key }}</a></td>
                    <td id="partners_nav_bracket">|</td>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The line {% if key in index|last %} is where i'm attempting to check if it is the last item in the iteration.

This does not produce any errors.Yet does not remove the pipe to the right of the letter Z.

Note:
Inside of index is an ordered dictionary which has a key for every letter in the alphabet. And some of these keys have values that are also a letter (the same letter)... This is to use the A | B | C as a jump to navigation at the top of the page. The rest of the keys have a value of None... So the letter still displays at the top of the page but it is not clickable

Comment: What's inside `index`?

Comment: maybe `{% if forloop.first %}` and `{% if forloop.last %}`  could help ?

Comment: @OzgurVatansever Inside of index is an ordered dictionary which has a key for every letter in the alphabet. And some of these keys have values that are also a letter (the same letter)... This is to use the A | B | C as a jump to navigation at the top of the page.

The rest of the keys have a value of None... So the letter still displays at the top of the page but it is not clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `forloop.first` or `forloop.last`.

```
<div class="row">
    <table align="center" cellpadding="4px">
        <tr>
        {% for key, value in index.items %}
            {% if value == None %}
                <td>{{ key }}</td>
            {% else %}
                <td><a href="{{ value }}">{{ key }}</a></td>
            {% endif %}

            {% if not forloop.last %}
                <td id="partners_nav_bracket">|</td>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I also cleaned up your markup, because the contents of your `if` and `else` were the same.

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup! Now what is morally correct to do. Accept your answer, or the others who came before. You cleaned up markup, and have smaller reputation.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check [`forloop.last`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for) template variable. It returns `True` if it is the last time through the loop:

```
{% for key, value in index.items %}
  ...
  {% if value %}
  <td><a href="{{ value }}">{{ key }}</a></td>
  {% else %}
  <td>{{ key }}</td>
  {% endif %}

  {% if not forloop.last %}
  <td id="partners_nav_bracket">|</td>
  {% endif %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```